# Using is vs was when talking about the past

Tags: tense, verbs, past-tense, present-tense, auxiliary-verbs

1. The reason why I liked "The Office" **is** probably because of the writing.
2. The reason why I liked "The Office" **was** probably because of the writing.

I'm not sure which one is correct. I still like "The Office", so should I say **is** instead of **was**?

"The reason", i.e., "the writing", still exists. It's not like the writing of the show ceased to exist. So, 1 might be correct, and 2 also seems correct.

**My question:**

1. Which of 1 and 2 is correct?
2. Did I use i.e. correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences (1 & 2) are correct.

In sentence 1, the verb in the main clause is in the *present* tense (**is**). So, the verb in the subordinate clause can be in any tense (**liked**). Therefore, the 1st sentence is correct.

In sentence 2, the verb in the main clause is in the *past* tense (**was**). So, the verb in subordinate clause must be in the past tense (**liked**). Therefore, the 2nd sentence is also correct.